# Angularjs UTC time to EST time zone by using date filter

Tags: angularjs, date, datetime

Angularjs `date` filter issue:

I have following date in my jSon:

```
2016-11-19T14:00:00
```

When I am using `{{value | date: 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a'}}` is shows 11/19/2016 02:00 PM

When I am using `{{value | date: 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a' | 'UTC'}}` is shows 11/19/2016 17:00 PM

When use JavaScript `getHours()` it gives time 09

I want to show the date  and time in EST format and time zone.

Comment: create a custom filter that takes utc time , subtracts timezone offset and returns appropriate string

Comment: I can do that but I was thinking if anyone have solution in angular way

Comment: Angular doesn't have anything in the api regarding timezone offsets or date calculations.

Comment: @AliAdravi **2016-11-19T14:00:00** what is your expected output value?

Comment: @Aravind `T` timezone designation is 2 hours behind the expected timezone. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UTC_time_offsets